# How do I customize an HTML template before sending it in an email using Meteor and Mandrill?

Tags: meteor, mandrill

I'm setting up an HTML template (not meteor template, but just a template written in HTML) and I need to plug in values for each donation received on our donation page. I will then submit that HTML file to Mandrill and it will send the file out to their email address. I don't know how to get started here. I just need a push in the right direction, or a resource to look for.

The question I have is, how do I add values into a static HTML file, then give that file to the Mandrill app without creating a new HTML file each time a receipt is sent and without changing the original file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look like I just needed to paste in the merge tag fields that I want to use, then reference them when I do my API call.

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-

So the template can have text like this, with the mergetag surrounded by `*|...|*`

`Dear *|FNAME|*,`

Then in the API call just tell Mandrill what fname should be replaced with.
```

```
"merge_vars": [
            {
                "rcpt": "emailadress@domain.com",
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "fname",
                        "content": "John"
                    },
```

```